# eliminating contraction

Tags: lo.logic, proof-theory

I'd like to better understand the role of the contraction rule in Gentzen's $\mathsf{LK}$. I would like to have an example of a derivable sequent that is no longer derivable if the contraction rule is replaced by "derive $\Sigma, A \wedge B \vdash \Delta$ from $\Sigma, A ,B \vdash \Delta$ and "derive $\Sigma \vdash A  \vee B , \Delta$ from $\Sigma \vdash A, B, \Delta$". I am particularly interested in the formulation of $\mathsf{LK}$ without the cut rule.

Comment: I think it would be good to be *very* precise about what you take as $\mathsf{LK}$, as little details here can matter. For instance, would the sequent calculus from Frank Pfenning's [notes on sequent calculus](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/15816-s10/lectures/08-seqcalc.pdf) be what you are looking for? (In particular, are $\Delta$ and $\Sigma$ sets or lists or multisets?)

Comment: $\Sigma$ and $\Delta$ are lists of formulas.

Comment: The statement of $\mathsf{LK}$ on wikipedia looks fine to me.

Comment: [The Wikipedia formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus#The_system_LK) is broken. It says that $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ are sets, but then it gives exchange and contraction as structural rules, which makes no sense for sets. Should we take $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ to be lists, or should we ignore exchange and contraction?

Comment: Yes, you are right; wikipedia has "sets" where it means "lists".

Comment: You can search for "substructural logic". The ultimate example is $A\vdash A\land A$. Note that without contraction, most connectives split into two. In the literature, $\land$ and $\lor$ are usually reserved for lattice conjunction and disjunction, using additive (shared-context) sequent rules. Multiplicative (split-context) conjunction, which is the one you defined in the question, tends to be denoted $\&$, $\cdot$, or $\otimes$; likewise, multiplicative disjunction is called $\oplus$. However, an incompatible notational convention was originally introduced for linear logic by Girard.